# How to detach a branch and reattach it to some different branch in Git

Tags: git

I have a master and topic branch forked from it as shown below:

```
A---B---C---D master
     \
      E---F topic
```

I want to detach this topic branch and attach it to my feature branch like shown below:

```
G---H---I---J feature
             \
              E---F topic
```

Here master and feature branches are present on both remote and local while the topic is only at my local. I want to push topic after reattaching it to feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `feature` contains `B`, then it's as simple as `git rebase feature` from the `topic` branch. If this is not the case, you'll need:

```
git rebase --onto feature B
```

The difference is because if `B` is not contained in `feature`, the rebase command won't know how far to wind back before replaying.

In general, `git rebase --onto X Y` means "replay all commits after `Y` on top of `X`". `git rebase X` is shorthand that first finds the common ancestor of `HEAD` and `X` (`Z = git merge-base HEAD X`), then replay all commits after `Z` on top of `X`.

Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: Yes the feature branch was not having B.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git checkout topic-branch
git rebase feature-branch
```

Git book has a chapter on the subject too, if you want more in-depth knowledge: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 1):

you need to checkout your topic branch

```
git checkout  \E--F(*topic branch)`
```

and then all of contents will be in sync with remote branch and then
you need to rebase your feature branch

```
git rebase G--H--I--J(*feature branch)
```

Comment: Why did you post this answer, when the answer below yours was posted before, and is exactly the same?

Comment: because my answer was more detailed and explaining.